# Upgrading .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.5 breaking images on Asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, .net, image, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

We recently updated our server to .NET 4.5 Framework from .NET 4.0 Framework. Prior to the update, everything was working. After the update, it appears that ASP:Image tags and ASP:ImageButton tags, and any other images that are runat="server" are showing up as broken images.

I've figured out why they're showing up as broken images, the src attribute is simply not being added to the img tag once it's generated as HTML, the problem I'm having is figuring out why that's happening.

Relevant code is below:

ASP:

```
<asp:imagebutton id="btnAdmin" Runat="server" ImageUrl="images/nav_b4.gif" Height="35" Width="79" CommandName="admin" AlternateText="Admin"></asp:imagebutton>
```

Generated HTML

```
<input type="image" name="btnAdmin" id="btnAdmin" onmouseout="tidyMenu(event);" onmouseover="openMenu(event,'nav_b4',1,5681366,16777215);setGraphic(event,'images/nav_b4_over.gif');return false;" alt="Admin" style="height:35px;width:79px;">
```

The onMouseOver and onMouseOut events are being attached by a JavaScript plugin later on, but that seems to have no effect on the actual processing of the image. In fact, if I hover over the button, the image will appear since that's what the JavaScript is doing, displaying different images for hovering.

I guess it's worth noting that this is happening even on the most basic of `<ASP:Image>` tags like:

`<asp:Image ImageUrl="images/j0285247.gif" runat="server" ID="leftIcon" />`

is showing up once the page loads as

`<img id="leftIcon">`

Unfortunately this is some legacy code we're working with so it's pretty ugly but I just need to make it work with .NET 4.5 and I'm lost as to why the src attribute isn't being attached to the img tag based on the ImageUrl attribute in the ASP tag.

We've tried some simple things like adding `~/` to the front of the ImageUrl path, but that hasn't helped, as I think it's less to do with the actual path, and more to do with something .NET 4.5 does that .NET 4.0 didn't.

If anyone has any ideas, that would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: setGraphic is one of the JavaScript functions, and when you mouseover the image does appear. All of the client side calls are working fine and the images will appear if I hover over them. The issue is the initial page load where the server should be finding the image. In that case, no, no URL calls are being made at all to try and find the image, which is how I found that it was just missing the src attribute all together.

Comment: Do you have any other JavaScript code that may be modifying the source on page load?

Comment: I tried removing all JS from the code just to see if it would change, and while the mouseout / mouseover code is not there, the issues are still happening. I guess it's worth noting that this is happening even on the most basic of `<ASP:Image>` tags like `<asp:Image ImageUrl="images/j0285247.gif" runat="server" ID="leftIcon" />` is showing up once the page loads as `<img id="leftIcon">`. I'll add that to the original question.

Comment: Have you tried it in a new Project that only renders a asp:Image?

Comment: We tried a new project and it still had the same issue as well. We did however find that the person who has ownership of the server managed to install the beta of .NET 4.5, instead of the production version, so this might be our underlying issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The person who manages our server mistakenly installed .NET 4.5 Beta, which after a lot of exploration, we found. After we contacted him to have him fix the issue, and once the .NET 4.5 production version was installed, the images are working again.